# Android : Read binary file failure

Tags: java, android, binary

I was try to read a binary file storing the position of x, y, z ,w.
that is, they are all float such as 1.4567896 5.156986 .....etc.

I successfully read it in c++ and also java, but couldn't done in android,
all I read in is all zero...

Here is my code : 
ps. I try many codes before, all failed...

```
public class DataIO {

    private int             DataSize = 640*320*4;
    private float[]         fDataBuffer;
    private byte[]          bDataBuffer;

    private String          sOutput;

    public DataIO(){
        bDataBuffer = new byte[DataSize*4];
        fDataBuffer = new float[DataSize];
    }

    /*=============================================
    *   Function:
    *       ReadFile
    *   Description:
    *       Read binary float data to float[] buffer.
    *================================================ */
    public void ReadFile(String FileName){
        File file = new File(FileName);
        try {
            FileInputStream finStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            if(finStream.read(bDataBuffer) == -1){
                Log.d("ReadData", "Reading Data has problem.");
            }

            finStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < DataSize; i+=1){
            /*int asInt = (bDataBuffer[i+0] & 0xFF)
                    | ((bDataBuffer[i+1] & 0xFF) << 8)
                    | ((bDataBuffer[i+2] & 0xFF) << 16)
                    | ((bDataBuffer[i+3] & 0xFF) << 24);
            fDataBuffer[index] = Float.intBitsToFloat(asInt);*/

            sOutput += String.format("%d ", bDataBuffer[i]);
            index++;
        }

    }

    /*=============================================
    *   Function:
    *       GetData
    *   Description:
    *       output the data by string.
    *================================================ */
    public String GetData(){
        return sOutput;
    }
}
```

> I blocked the transformation of byte to float cuz read in byte have to be check if they are correct first.

Comment: The solution is okay, though the last for loop walks just the first quarter, and string concatenation as done there is nothing for production. If you are getting "0 0 0 0 0 ...." in `sOutput` better inspect the file (file path). Remarks: the code style is not javaish (is Hungarian, capitalized methods). Floats are seemingly stored in little endian order. One could have used a `FloatBuffer.order(LITTLE_ENDIAN)`. No length check. But fine code is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again.
The file is correct and I got the file path "/document/150E-0810:Download/1.pcd" I think it's also correct ...maybe.
I'm not sure which naming style I used I some Time use iData, fData, sometimes FloatData,IntData, and also Data_x Data_Y...etc.
Which one is better~~??

Comment: Maybe in front of the for loop: `sOutput = fileName + ": "` or such;

Answer (score 0):

On Android you need to use a runnable interface to constantly check a variable.